# Why is the Android SDK throwing a Permissions Required message when my app doesn't require any?

Tags: android, permissions

My Android app is targeting SDK 34 and after users sign in with their email address, the device shows a "Permissions Required" dialog, even though none are required. The SDK is displaying the message, not the app, so I'm puzzled where the message is coming from.

Comment: I think we need more details in order to be able to help you. What features do your app uses? (network, bluetooth, services...) And when did you observed the crashes(what changed? you bumped the target SDK from which version to 34?)?

Comment: The Android SDK runs on your device? How did you manage?

Comment: Which permission is required? Should we guess?

Comment: The message didn't say which which permissions were required and according to Settings, none are required.

Comment: @Cata The app doesn't crash. In fact, the app had been running fine for the last few years. It had made requested READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but I commented both out after reading that for SDK 34, they were no longer required. As for SDK 34, I updated the project gradle file to use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'.

Comment: The permissions itself won't make your app crash, instead, the usage of sensitive APIs(the ones that require permissions to be granted) could. Have you tested your app? Are you able to reproduce the issue your users are facing?